# Run a PHP function on success of AJAX request completion

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know that in JS, you can use the success of an AJAX function as the trigger to start other events...

So I have just loaded a new page using AJAX. And through this I have also passed some parameters, this is what I have passed:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","register-form.php?one="+wordChoiceOne+"&two="+wordChoiceTwo+"&three="+wordChoiceThree,true);
```

So I now have the variables `$one, $two, $three` in PHP

I want to complete a couple of tasks using these (concatenate, capitalise, assign etc) before outputting onto the page. However I don't want this to be bound to the click of a button or anything, I want it to be bound to **the success of the AJAX load**.

How can I now start these actions in PHP?

*Pseudo-code*:

```
function setUsername() // RUN ON AJAX SUCCESS{
     // capitalise first letter of one two and three
     // concatenate together
     // Store in variable $username
}
```

Then `ECHO USERNAME OUT`

ETA. I have already written the AJAX request and it works fine. Now it's loaded, I want to perform this PHP function, binding the trigger of that function to the success of the AJAX load:

```
<?php

$_GET['one'], $_GET['two'] and $_GET['three'];

// Capitalise first letter
$one = ucfirst($one); 
$two = ucfirst($two); 
$three = ucfirst($three); 

$username = $one . $two . $three;

?>
```

**EDIT:** OK so it appears I can't explain myself, or I haven't understood what is required for this functionality. But here is what I need to happen in plain english, with links.

I am building a registration system. Instead of letting people type in their own username, I have a username builder. You can see this here:
http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/register-username-builder.php

**Step One in Javascript**

You drag the tiles into the boxes, hit the button that shows up. When you have all three, you hit the big green button. Up until this point, we are all in jQuery, and we have the following three variables stored:

`wordChoiceOne` - the first word you choose
`wordChoiceTwo` - the second word you choose
`wordChoiceThree` - the third word you choose

These are stored as JS variables.

**Step Two PHP time**

So now that I have these three stored variables I wish to move away from JS and start using PHP. I have already built a successfully working registration but it uses the `username` as an input rather than this when helps you "build" your own.

My research has led to the understanding that because of the client side to server side switch the only way that I can successfully pass these variables into PHP is through an AJAX request. This seems pretty handy to me because I would like the registration form I have already built to be loaded into the page asynchronously. So I asked for some advice about how to "share" these jQuery values through the AJAX request and was helped with the following, to pass them through the URL:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","register-form.php?one="+wordChoiceOne+"&two="+wordChoiceTwo+"&three="+wordChoiceThree,true);
```

My understanding (and maybe I'm wrong? Please let me know and explain if I am...) is that this assigns the already existing variables of wordChoiceTwo etc to a PHP variable of $two. Is this right?

So now I have PHP variables $one, $two and $three...

**Running the PHP**

Perhaps this is because I am more used to working with JS, but with JS you have to *do something* (button click etc) to be able to enact a function. I know that one such *do something* is a successul AJAXC request but that isn't PHP. So my question... and this was really the only question I had, is ** how do you start the running of a PHP function when you've just loaded somethhing through AJAX?** I want to start running a php function called `setUsername" on this page. But I don't want the user to have to press a button to make this start, I want it to be **bound to the success of the AJAX completion** or something similar to this, as I understand that might be JS only.

This is the AJAX call I already have in place:

```
function saveUsername(wordChoiceOne, wordChoiceTwo, wordChoiceThree){

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("login-register-wrapper").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }


xmlhttp.open("GET","register-form.php?one="+wordChoiceOne+"&two="+wordChoiceTwo+"&three="+wordChoiceThree,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be invoked from a client, not from `register-form.php`?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I am not explaining myself. I don't want it to be invoked from there, but I want it to happen when the register-form.php loads. Is it possible to enact PHP just on file load?

Comment: why do you want your app to rely on a non-reliable client whereas you already have the data passed to a server?

Comment: Why do you say that? All I want to do is take some variables which have been made using jQuery and do something with them in PHP....

Comment: I'm saying that because it looks like you're expecting the `one`, `two` and `three` don't change between requests.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean at all. I have three jQuery variables. I now wish to convert them to PHP, as I have done above with AJAX. Now I want to do something with those PHP variables... and I am asking how.

Comment: I'm totally lost at this point them. From your question - you want to perform 2 ajax requests. Is it correct?

Comment: The AJAX request has already been performed, the code is from the AJAX request I have already written. I now have variables one, two, three. I now want to make a PHP function that does some stuff to them (I have called it setUsername.php). I want to call this PHP function when the AJAX request above has successfully completed.

Comment: Well, maybe I am wrong then. Can you explain what is wrong about what I have above and provide an answer in that case?

Comment: OK, so are you able to offer a solution?

Comment: wait, before things get out of hand. I think there's a basic misunderstanding of the `xmlhttprequest` here. Your php can return whatever after receiving the variables. just try it with an `echo json_encode(array('success'=>true))` after setting the php header to `application/json` and add a `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()` to your xmlhttp object

Comment: What do you want to do with the `$username`? Store it in the serverside session, send it back to the client, use in some additional processing?

Comment: Would it help if I just outlined exactly what I am trying to achieve with zero code in the post above? Like... what I am actually wanting to happen on screen. Maybe I am explaining myself wrong but if I don't know what I don't understand... how can I ask you what I want?

Comment: Thanks a lot CBroe, I have used ajax successfully elsewhere on the site. If you don't want to answer please don't.

Comment: @I have updated the post with a plain-english explanation of what I am looking for. If I am wrong in my understanding of something that's fine. But I'd appreciate if I am wrong, rather than telling me to go away and give up, someone is able to see where I'm wrong and perhaps offer a solution on what I should be doing. I've updated the OP with plenty of info for my desired end result and a lengthy explanation of how I got there.

Answer (score 1):

Add a json header type and echo

```
$_GET['one'], $_GET['two'] and $_GET['three'];

// Capitalise first letter
$one = ucfirst($one); 
$two = ucfirst($two); 
$three = ucfirst($three); 

$username = $one . $two . $three;
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('username'=>$username)); // <---
```

then in your js, bind a function to the success of the call:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     //xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
```

**edit**, because there seems to be some confusion:

Just because an ajax call *reaches* your php script *doesn't mean it's executed*. The request by nature will sit and wait for a reply. This reply can contain data if your php echo's it.

**edit 2** so you can wrap your head around the principle of it, here's an oversimplification of what I think you want:

file 'ajax.html':

```
<div id="name"></div>
<script>
    function myName(first, last) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'ajax.php?first='+first+'&last='+last);

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {
                data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = data.username;
            }
        }
        req.send();
    }
    myName('john', 'doe')
</script>
```

file 'ajax.php':

```
$first = $_GET['first'];
$last = $_GET['last'];
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('username'=>ucwords($first) . ' ' . ucwords($last)));
```

this is generally how AJAX is used

Comment: I guess the part I'm confused about is how you can bind the PHP function to the success of the AJAX, as my understanding was that you can only bind another JS function to the success of the AJAX. Perhaps that isn't correct? I'll give this a go but admittedly I'm not sure which part it should go in (in the new page that has been loaded in?) OP has been updated with links and explanation.

Comment: No, the PHP has nothing to do with it. the success of the ajax call in your mind seems to PHP receiving the variables, but it's actually the web servers response, which is nothing more than your post man putting a package in your mail box. You still have to do something with the contents of the package.

Comment: Just google search for a php ajax tutorial that returns data on success. You do seem to be missing some of the AJAX fundamentals.

Comment: I only learnt to use it last week so yes, I probably have. I thought I had passed the data through the request just fine but it appears I haven't.

Comment: I have put the PHP at the top of my new register-form.php file (which is called in). But I am now not able to get the data passing through the URL (the first bit of code in my OP) to work as it says error not found for the URL...

Comment: You can view the site here if you need more context. I tried adding the variables to the string but it then refuses to load the page: http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/register-username-builder.php